# JQuery fadeIn fadeOut loop issue

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to create a jQuery fadeIn fadeout effect for my page content using the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$("#main").click(function(){
    $("#content").fadeOut(800, function(){
        $("#content").load("main.html", function(){
            $("#content").fadeIn(800);
        });
    });
});

$("#gallery").click(function(){
    $("#content").fadeOut(800, function(){
        $("#content").load("gallery.html", function(){
            $("#content").fadeIn(800);
        });
    });
});

});
```

So whenever a user clicks on either the main link or gallery link, the old content fades out and new content fades in. The problem I am facing is that for every link I have to repeat the same code again and again. So I tried to use a loop to simplify this but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
var p = ["#main","#gallery", "#contact"];
var q = ["main.html", "gallery.html", "contact.html"];
for (i=0;i<=(p.length-1);i++){
    $(p[i]).click(function(){
    $("#content").fadeOut(500, function(){
        $("#content").load(q[i], function(){
            $("#content").fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
});
}
```

It works fine when I write repeat the scripts for each link but it doesn't work when I combine them in a loop. I only get the FadeOut effect and nothing happens after that.

This might be a very simple issue or may be something deep into jQuery. Any hint or help is greatly appreciated.

TK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to capture the current value of `i` or `q[i]` in a separate closure, like:

```
function buildChangeOverTo(src)
{
    return function() {
        var content = $("#content");
        content.fadeOut(500, function(){
           content.load(src, function(){
               content.fadeIn(500);
        }});
    }
}

var p = ["#main","#gallery", "#contact"];
var q = ["main.html", "gallery.html", "contact.html"];
for (i=0;i<=(p.length-1);i++) {
    $(p[i]).click(buildChangeOverTo(q[i]));
}
```

There are tons of information about those strange javascript closures on the web.

Comment: I understand now.. I guess my javaScript skills are not as good as I thought they were.. Thank you Wikser

Answer (score 0):

your i variable is always evaluated at 3, which makes q[i] undefined.  you'll have to find a way, like a class perhaps to persist the number associated through to the callback.

if it really is just the three links i'd suggest something simpler like a case statement.

```
switch $(this).attr('id') {
    case 'gallery' : ; break;
    case 'contact' : y; break;
    case 'main' : z; break;
}
```

and if you're worried about code duplication just write a function that accepts what page to load and call it in each .click()

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle that problem by adding a class to the links, say fadeLink and I would add a custom attribute to the link like fadeUrl. I would set the link destinations into the fadeUrl attribute on each link and then your document ready code could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".fadeLink").click(function(){
        var jqThis = $(this);
        $("#content").fadeOut(800, function(){
            $("#content").load(jqThis.attr("fadeUrl"), function(){
                $("#content").fadeIn(800);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This would side-step the loop and to add or edit links in the future you only have to change the data on the links.